# Mapping Excel Columns to Parent-Child JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a CSV input like this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,f,,
a,g,h,i,
j,k,l,,
j,k,m,n,
o,,,,
```

And I'm trying to transform that into a JSON output that complies with this format (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json) so I can leverage d3.js to visualize the parent-child tree (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570).

I'm looking to visualize my data exactly like that example, but I don't have/need weights. If need be, I can add a common first-level parent. Just looking to visualize the tree(s).

Largest depth is always 5.

I was playing around with doing some array stuff in PHP (after reading in with fgetcsv()), but I was bumbling around and could use some help.

PHP or Javascript solution preferred, since that's all I can work with through my work computer setup. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest) is what you need for transforming the flat array to a nested structure. Before that, [`d3.csv.parse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) is how you transform your CSV to a flat array of objects (assuming it's been loaded already).

Comment: @meetamit: Ahh why didn't I think of that. Silly me, and thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a tree structure where your data looks like the following:

```
          a            j      o
         / \          /
        b   g        k
       / \   \      / \
      c   f   h    l   m
     /         \        \
    d           i        n
   /
  e
```

if so, the following javascript code should do what you want:

```
var csv = //CSV CONTENT HERE
  , data = parseCSV(csv)
  , structure = toJSONStructure(data)
  , formattedForD3 = toNameChildFormat(structure)

console.log(formattedForD3)

function parseCSV(csv) {
    return csv.split('\n').slice(1).map(function(line) {
        return line.split(',')
    })
}

function toJSONStructure(data) {
    var structure = {}
    data.forEach(function(line) {
        var o = structure
        line.forEach(function(val) {
            if(val) o = o[val] = o[val] || {}
        })
    })
    return structure
}

function toNameChildFormat(structure) {
   return Object.keys(structure).map(function(key) {
       return {
           name:key,
           children:toNameChildFormat(structure[key])
       }
   })
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wo6q8nn/1/)